# What is a reasonable way of keeping track of multiple windows in PyQt?

Tags: windows, pyqt, data-members

I'm writing a PyQt application that shall feature multiple windows. Right now, I am interested in having one of two windows open at a time (so a click of a button in one window causes a switch to the other window). What is a reasonable way of keeping track of multiple windows in a PyQt application? My initial attempt, as shown below, essentially stores instances of the `QtGui.QWidget` in data members of a *global* instance of a simple class.

I'm new to PyQt. Is there a better way to approach this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Program(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent = None
        ):
        self.interface = Interface1()

class Interface1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent = None
        ):
        super(Interface1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button1.setText("button")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.clickedButton1)

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 350, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('interface 1')
        self.show()

    def clickedButton1(self):
        self.close()
        program.interface = Interface2()

class Interface2(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent = None
        ):
        super(Interface2, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.button1.setText("button")
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.clickedButton1)

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 350, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('interface 2')
        self.show()

    def clickedButton1(self):
        self.close()
        program.interface = Interface1()

def main():
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application.setApplicationName('application')
    global program
    program = Program()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a single main window with a [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) to hold the different interfaces. Then use [QStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) to switch between the interfaces.

Also, try to avoid using global references. If you want GUI components to communicate with each other, use signals and slots. You can easily [define your own custom signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) if there are no suitable built-in ones.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This appears to be a reasonable way to approach this problem.